# AppRTC deployment error

Tags: javascript, python

I deployed AppRTC on Google Cloud Engine. When I Join the call, I get the following error on the second peer:

```
Messages:  
Room server join error: Failed to join the room: Status=500, response=
Error: Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.
```

My Turn server URL is

```
TURN_SERVER_OVERRIDE = [
{
 "urls": [
   "stun:numb.viagenie.ca"
 ],
 "username": "xxxxxxx",
 "credential": "xxxxxx"
 },
]
```

And Base URLS

```
TURN_BASE_URL = 'https://computeengineondemand.appspot.com'
TURN_URL_TEMPLATE = '%s/turn?username=%s&key=%s'
CEOD_KEY = '4080218913'

ICE_SERVER_BASE_URL = 'https://networktraversal.googleapis.com'
ICE_SERVER_URL_TEMPLATE = '%s/v1alpha/iceconfig?key=%s'
ICE_SERVER_API_KEY = os.environ.get('ICE_SERVER_API_KEY')
```

[image]
And How to configure collider using go command??